# Update ListView in Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

Forgive my ignorance of Android. I'm just learning. I'm building an app that uses Google's SlidingTabsColors sample code for the main layout [(The developer website)](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html)
.

I've got the layout working the way I want it to with dummy data. The idea is each tab will store a user's score for each round and then display their total score so far at the bottom.

[image: Screenshot]

Knowing what's where is helpful. The `ListView` and `TextView` are in the `ViewPager`, the `Button` at the bottom is part of the fragment containing the tabs and the `ViewPager`. Currently, when the button is pressed, a new entry is added to each player's data set (an `ArrayList<Integer>') with the value of` 0`. The user can then tap an item and edit it.

That's what works. But the `ListView` doesn't update unless it's told to. So when you click the button, there is no change to the UI until you swipe to the next item and the fragment is refreshed. So everything is being added correctly, I just don't know how to tell the current `ListView` to update.

Here's the code for the `addRound()` method in the parent fragment:

```
public void addRound() {
    // add a blank round for each player in their dataset
    for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
        mData.get(i).second.add(0);
    }

    // get the pager adapter
    DefaultGameFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (DefaultGameFragmentPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
    
    int pos = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    ContentFragment frag = (ContentFragment) adapter.getItem(pos);
    if (frag != null) {
        frag.update();
    }
}
```

And the `update()` method in `ContentFragment`:

```
public void update() {
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to access my custom ArrayAdapter, but if I'm getting the current fragment from the `ViewPager`, shouldn't all those members be initialized? (The `ListView` is set up in the `onViewCreated()` method)

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Justin

Comment: Howdie. I'd actually like to see more of the code but let's see if I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentFragment frag = (ContentFragment) adapter.getItem(pos);`

Never use `getItem()` function of the adapter to get the current fragment from ViewPager. It is called internally to instantiate the fragment and we are not supposed to call it explicitly. The Fragment returned by calling `getItem` is not the actual fragment present in `ViewPager` at that position. So update call doesn't update the data in intended fragment.

Try using one of the methods discussed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager).

Comment: This doesn't answer @justinrixx's question.

Comment: The Fragment returned by calling getItem is not the actual fragment present in ViewPager at that position. So update call doesn't update the data in intended fragmnet.

Comment: Now this comment is admittedly more of an explanatory answer than your first - explaining why, instead of telling what.  I'd upvote this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that `getItem` shouldn't be called. I sort of figured if it's a public method, it'd be ok to use. Bu that explains why I got a null pointer.
I appreciate the link you posted, I ended up using the Fragment manager to get the fragment by its tag, and it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Okay Justinrixx, let's try few things:

First, let's create a public method in your Fragment which returns the instance of your ArrayAdapter e.g `getScoreAdapter()`.

Second, let's create a public method in your custom ArrayAdapter to (re)set the dataset e.g. `setDataset(ArrayList<int> playerScores);`

Now in your `addRound()` method, after you ensure the frag isn't null, get the instance of your adapter via `getScoreAdapter()`, then, on that instance, set adapter's new data set via `setDataset()` and by proving the new data set.  And last, call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Goes without saying, your custom ArrayAdapter should hold an instance of the dataset it uses, either passed in constructor or set with our new method `setDataset()` method.

The reason of my suggestion was due to what I see or don't see in your code; in other words, I couldn't see reliably how your adapter received the changed dataset; hence my suggestion of clearly setting new datasets to adapters, making sure adapters keep using the new set dataset and finally notifying them of the change.  Hope this helps.